# Создание спецификации в цикле

Tags: java, sql, spring

Всем привет, такой вопрос.
Есть список который может содержать более 1000 элементов, по которому надо сделать сравнение. Oracle не позволяет добавить в один 'in' более 1000 элементов, по этому хочу через цикл разбить один большой запрос на несколько поменьше. Для этого использую следующий метод (в коде ограничено числом 3 чтобы локально воспроизвести, в h2 лежит меньше сущностей):

```
    public Page<DivisionView> getDivisions(Pageable pageable, String q, Long macroRegionId) {
    User loggedUser = userRepository.findOne(idEquals(SecurityContextUtils.getLoggedUserId()));
    Set<Long> shopIds = shopRepository.findAll(shopService.specificationByRole(loggedUser)).stream().map(Shop::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    Specification<OrgStructureDivision> specification = null;
    Specification<OrgStructureDivision> shopSpecification = null;

    Set<Long> thousandIds = new HashSet<>();
    for (Long id: shopIds) {
        if (thousandIds.size() < 3) {
            thousandIds.add(id);

        } else {
            shopSpecification = divisionSpecificationForThousandIds(shopSpecification, thousandIds);
            thousandIds.clear();
        }
    }

    shopSpecification = divisionSpecificationForThousandIds(shopSpecification, thousandIds);

    specification = where(specification).and(shopSpecification);

    return repository.findAll(specification, pageable).map(DivisionView::buildFromEntity);
}


private Specification<OrgStructureDivision> divisionSpecificationForThousandIds(Specification<OrgStructureDivision> shopSpecification, Set<Long> thousandIds) {

    return shopSpecification == null
            ? shopIn(thousandIds)
            : where(shopSpecification).or(shopIn(thousandIds));
}
```

Есть спецификация:

```
    public static Specification<OrgStructureDivision> shopIn(Set<Long> shopIds) {
    return (root, criteriaQuery, cb) -> {
        criteriaQuery.distinct(true);

        Join<OrgStructureCluster, Shop> shopJoin = root.join(OrgStructureDivision_.clusters).join(OrgStructureCluster_.shops);

        return shopJoin.in(shopIds);
    };
}
```

на выходе получается что то вроде:

```
select distinct orgstructu0_.division_id     as division1_41_,
            orgstructu0_.external_id     as external2_41_,
            orgstructu0_.external_system as external3_41_,
            orgstructu0_.active          as active4_41_,
            orgstructu0_.guid            as guid5_41_,
            orgstructu0_.macro_region_id as macro_re7_41_,
            orgstructu0_.name            as name6_41_
from structure_division orgstructu0_
         inner join structure_cluster clusters1_ on orgstructu0_.division_id = clusters1_.division_id
         inner join shop shops2_ on clusters1_.id = shops2_.cluster_id
         inner join structure_cluster clusters3_ on orgstructu0_.division_id = clusters3_.division_id
         inner join shop shops4_ on clusters3_.id = shops4_.cluster_id
where (shops4_.id in (5) or shops2_.id in (5));
```

Проблема в том что в списке приходит (-2, 1, 2, 4, 5) а в спецификации всё обрубается и несколько раз по in (5) проверяет.
Подскажите пожалуйста с чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен но в вашем варианте два раза вызов есть в цикле и потом без цикла

> divisionSpecificationForThousandIds

Как вариант сделать временную таблицу и запихнуть туда все id.
А потом сделать

> your_sql WHERE some_id IN ( SELECT some_id FROM some_tmp_table )

Comment: без цикла чтобы если список будет меньше 1000 элементов или если на одной из итераций до конца не заполнится добавить всё равно в спецификацию